# NVIDIA Video Codec Samples giving ffmpeg errors while trying to build

Tags: nvidia, h.264, codec, video-encoding

My computer environment：
Driver：510.108.03
CUDA：11.1
NVIDIA Video Codec SDK：11.1.5
FFmpeg：4.4 (Comes with SDK)

When I compile SDK Samples, the following error occurs:

```
[ 15%] Building CXX object AppEncode/AppEncDec/CMakeFiles/AppEncDec.dir/AppEncDec.cpp.o
In file included from /home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/AppEncode/AppEncDec/AppEncDec.cpp:30:0:
/home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/Utils/../Utils/FFmpegStreamer.h: In constructor ‘FFmpegStreamer::FFmpegStreamer(AVCodecID, int, int, int, const char*)’:
/home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/Utils/../Utils/FFmpegStreamer.h:48:13: error: ‘AVFormatContext {aka struct AVFormatContext}’ has no member named ‘url’
         oc->url = av_strdup(szInFilePath);
             ^~~
/home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/Utils/../Utils/FFmpegStreamer.h:49:55: error: ‘AVFormatContext {aka struct AVFormatContext}’ has no member named ‘url’
         LOG(INFO) << "Streaming destination: " << oc->url;
                                                       ^~~
/home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/Utils/../Utils/FFmpegStreamer.h:67:36: error: ‘AVFormatContext {aka struct AVFormatContext}’ has no member named ‘url’
         if (avio_open(&oc->pb, oc->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
                                    ^~~
/home/plusgo/plusgo/Projects/test/Video_Codec_SDK_11.1.5/Samples/Utils/../Utils/FFmpegStreamer.h:68:60: error: ‘AVFormatContext {aka struct AVFormatContext}’ has no member named ‘url’
             LOG(ERROR) << "FFMPEG: Could not open " << oc->url;
```

I suspect it is a problem with the FFmpeg version, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to install FFmpeg4.4.4 by myself. But it didn't work.